# Handling "Popup" Window.xaml in PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm developing a WPF application with MVVM and PRISM 7.

At some places I'd like to open a new `Window.xaml` with the click of a button.

So I've created that `Window.xaml` and am calling it like so when clicking that button/command:

```
private void OnInstrumentFinderCommand()
{
    var instrumentfinder = new InstrumentFinderWindow();
    var result = instrumentfinder.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        // logic here...   
    }
}
```

That works fine. The `InstrumentFinderWindow` opens up and I can interact with it.

But this breaks the loosely coupling which I want to achieve with MVVM.

I know how to use PRISM with `View`s and `Module`s, but cannot figure out how I have to handle the `Window` to achieve the same result as the code above, but loosely coupled resp. not calling it directly from within a `ViewModel`.

Is there even a way or do I have to handle this completely different?

**EDIT:**
I just want to make clear, that I'm asking about a way to call a `System.Windows.Window` a MVVM/PRISM-way. Not about a "Yes/No/Cancel" popup dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling popup dialog in PRISM-way can be done with ***Interaction User Experience***.

This way is thoroughly described [in PRISM documentation](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/legacy/Advanced-MVVM.html#using-behaviors-to-implement-the-interaction-user-experience) and there are bunch of examples how to do it properly [in prism samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf) (25-NotificationRequest, 26-ConfirmationRequest, 27-CustomContent, 28-CustomRequest).

Declare `InteractionRequest<T>` property in your ViewModel:

```
public InteractionRequest<Notification> FindInstrumentRequest { get; }
```

Raise request inside command

```
private void OnInstrumentFinderCommand() {
    FindInstrumentRequest.Raise(
        new Notification(), 
        notification =>
        {
             //the dialog shown, logic here
        });
}
```

Add interaction trigger to the window View

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding FindInstrumentRequest}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:InstrumentFinderWindow />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

...

</UserControl>
```

Implement `IInteractionRequestAware` interface by `InstrumentFinderWindowViewModel` and finish interaction with FinishInteraction invoking.

```
public partial class InstrumentFinderWindowViewModel: UserControl, IInteractionRequestAware
{
    private void SelectInstrument()
    {
        FinishInteraction?.Invoke();
    }

    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }
    public INotification Notification { get; set; }
}
```

You can create derived type of `NotificationRequest` and use it to pass data between window and dialog.

**IMPORTANT ADDITION:**
This interaction mechanism will be removed in feature versions of PRISM. There is new way to handle dialog is being implemented now: [DialogService](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1682). It is in pre-release version of PRISM library.

Comment: Thanks, Aleksei. I'll have a look on the old an new approach.

Comment: Aleksei have you tried out the new DialogService yourself?

Comment: No, I haven't. I decided to stick to the old way until new service will be release in NuGet.

Comment: Hopefully soon. ;) Would you put my `InstrumentFinderWindow` in a PRISM module or leave it in the main project, where the main application/shell lays?

Comment: It depends on how often do I need to change without recompiling the main program. For example, if I have 2 different versions Instrument Finder Windows for different editions of the product. Or instrument finder window is an add-on, which could be shipped separately, could have many implementations by different teams and could be changed on client side.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm still struggling with understanding and would appreciate help from you again: in your sample code, you've used a `UserControl`. Which leads me to think, that this is implemented in a `Region` of the `Shell`. My goal was to have `Window.xaml` to be openend in a modal way. Is this possible? I havn't implemented anything yet, because I wanted to read more about it.

Comment: The XAML from my sample code is in **main window**. Anyway, instrument finder will be a UserControl, too. It will be opened in a modal way because of `IsModal="True"` in interaction trigger. Prism automatically creates window and puts UserControl you provided in it.

Comment: Ahh perfect! Thanks a lot!